# Idiomatic way to simultanously transform map and filter null results

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to map over the keys of a `table = Map<K, V>` with `f: (K) -> M?` and get a `Map<M, V>`. However, all of my attemps are a little bit smelly:

- `table.mapKeys{ f(it.key) }.filter{it != null} as Map<M, V>` seems the most straightforward, but has to be cast from `Map<M?, V>` to `Map<M, V>` manually. The unchecked cast sidesteps the null-checking "ecosystem", which seems off (and causes the IDE to whine).
- `table.filterKeys(f(it) != null).mapKeys(f)` is simple, but applies `f` twice, which feels stupid.
- I also considered `table.mapNotNull { f(it.key)?.let {res -> res to it.value} }.toMap()`, but the creation of an intermediate list is highly unappealing.

I sense that there should be a straightforward declarative (i.e. no `MutableMap`) way of achieving this transformation, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

You could add utility functions that do this for yourself:

```
inline fun <K, V, R : Any> Map<K, V>.mapKeysNotNull(transform: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R?): Map<R, V> {
    return mapKeysNotNullTo(LinkedHashMap(), transform)
}

inline fun <K, V, R : Any> Map<K, V>.mapKeysNotNullTo(destination: MutableMap<R, V>, transform: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R?): Map<R, V> {
    forEach { element -> transform(element)?.let { destination.put(it, element.value) } }
    return destination
}
```

This is the long version of this code, to match the style of the standard library collection extension implementations as closely as possible. You could simplify this if you want, like this for example:

```
inline fun <K, V, R : Any> Map<K, V>.mapKeysNotNull(transform: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R?): Map<R, V> {
    val destination = LinkedHashMap<R, V>()
    forEach { element -> transform(element)?.let { destination.put(it, element.value) } }
    return destination
}
```

Either way, the call you're trying to make would look like this using the above:

```
table.mapKeysNotNull(f)
```